# Are there potential Ribbis issues with applying for PPP loans?

Tags: politics-government, lending-interest-ribbis, borrowing, covid19-pandemic

I guess this questions has two components to it:

(1) Are [PPP loans](https://www.sba.gov/funding-programs/loans/coronavirus-relief-options/paycheck-protection-program) different than other types of loans because of the way it's structured with the government guaranteeing the loans or something to that effect, and the fact that it's forgiveable.

(2) What are the general ribbis rules about borrowing from a bank that has Jewish shareholders or partner? One of big PPP processors, Paypal, uses a lender called [Webbank](https://www.webbank.com/), which is a subsidiary of Steel Partners, which is a public partnership run by a guy Warren Lichtenstein. Is that definitely problematic?